# implementing flood fill algorithm

Tags: vb.net

I have decided to use a flood fill algorithm for my application, using this pseudo-code from Wikipedia:

```
Flood-fill (node, target-color, replacement-color):
     1. Set Q to the empty queue.
     2. If the color of node is not equal to target-color, return.
     3. Add node to Q.
     4. For each element n of Q:
     5.  If the color of n is equal to target-color:
     6.   Set w and e equal to n.
     7.   Move w to the west until the color of the node to the west of w no longer matches target-color.
     8.   Move e to the east until the color of the node to the east of e no longer matches target-color.
     9.   Set the color of nodes between w and e to replacement-color.
    10.   For each node n between w and e:
    11.    If the color of the node to the north of n is target-color, add that node to Q.
           If the color of the node to the south of n is target-color, add that node to Q.
    12. Continue looping until Q is exhausted.
    13. Return.
```

I was doing alright, until I hit the "continue looping until Q is exhausted".
I don't quite get that. How is Q exhausted?

Answer (score 0):

This is a way of turning a recursive function into an iterative one. Instead of pushing each pixel onto the stack (recursing), you add it to the queue. You're right, this will extend the range of iterations, but that's what you want to do. It keeps expanding as it finds new pixels that match the seed color.

If I understand correctly, you're concerned about editing the size of the queue while using the "for each" statement. The algorithm pseudo-code is confusing in this regard; where it says:

```
For each element n of Q:
...
Continue looping until Q is exhausted.
```

Think of it instead as:

```
while Q is not empty:
  dequeue element n of Q
  check the pixels
```

This will exhaust the queue.

Answer (score -1):

After you process a node in Q (after step 11, before going back through the loop), you remove it. Eventually you'll stop adding elements to Q, and then you'll just go through the rest and process them one at a time.

Comment: But will adding nodes to Q extend the range of iterations of the For loop? I think there was another language where, in a similar scenario, I would get an error if I did that...